# Backup in SSIS using a Variable db name

Tags: variables, ssis, backup

I have an SSIS flow that creates a database from a variable (and alters a couple of settings).

Now, I need to create an initial backup of that database (and then add it to a backup plan).

Ask: How do I use the variable I used to create the database to also run the initial backup?  (I am trying to use the Backup task...but if an Execute SQL task is better, I'm open to that.)

Comment: The Execute SQL Task is going to be far more flexible than the Backup Task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an SSIS variable named `@[User::DatabaseName]`

Given that a backup command would look something like

```
BACKUP DATABASE [MyDB] TO DISK = N'\\Server\backup\MyDB\MyDB_backup_2020_05_06_020003.bak' WITH NOFORMAT,
NOINIT,  
NAME = N'MyDb-Full Database Backup', 
SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```

I'd create SSIS variables.

`@[User::BackupTimestamp]` string Expression something like

```
(DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR(@[System::StartTime])
+ "_"
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH(@[System::StartTime]), 2)
+ "_"
+ RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR, 2) DAY(@[System::StartTime]), 2)
+ "_"
... repeat the above pattern to slice out hours, minutes, seconds into 2 digit entities
```

The purpose of this is to generate a string representation of the start time of the package with the level of time/date precision we want with our backups.

`@[User::BackupCommand]` This is going to be concatenated from other variables to build out the correct TSQL command.

```
"BACKUP DATABASE [" 
+ @[User::DatabaseName] 
+ "] TO DISK = N'\\\\double\\escape\\slashes\\" 
+ @[User::DatabaseName] 
+ "\\" + @[User::DatabaseName] 
+ "_" + @[User::BackupTimestamp]
+ ".bak WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME= N'" 
+ @[User::DatabaseName] 
+ "-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, STATS=10;"
```

As you can see, slashes are a bit of a pain as you have to double them inside Expressions. I typically create a variable called `BackupPath` which simplifies that bit.

Take the generated command, run it via SSMS and if it works, then you can simply wire up the SqlCommand/Text (property name aproximate) to that variable.

As for "add it to a backup plan", I don't know what plan your organization uses. I'm a fan of anything that backs up any database it finds as mechanically adding something to a process is a step that will have be missed at the most inopportune time. Ola's backup scripts, Minionware, etc